# Captcha's + Differnet Possibilities

Tags: captcha

I wanted to run some captcha possibities past people to see if they are easily by passed by bots etc.

1. What if colors were used - eg: there is a string of 10 characters are you ask people to type the red characters of where there are 5? Easy to bypass?
2. I've noticed a captcha on plentyoffish that involves typing in the characters under the circles. This seems a touch more complex - would this be more challenging for bots?
   [image: captcha]
   <sub>(source: [pof.com](https://www.pof.com/JpegImage.aspx?nc=a&key=lv2sag04liv44mh5lvuyylr0&rand=244039&side=1))</sub>
3. The other idea I was thinking was putting the requirement in an image as well meaning like in no. 1 above - you can put "type the red characters" in an image and this could change with different colors. Any value here?

Interested in what people think.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Colours are easy to bypass. A bot just takes the red channel and gets the answer. It is even easier than choosing between many possible solutions. The same applies to any noise that has another colour than the letters the user needs to find.
2. <del>Symbols that don't touch the letters are very easy to ignore. Why would a bot even look at those circles that probably always stay at the same position?</del> (valid but wasn't asked here)
3. Identifying circles or other symbols is easier than identifying letters, if one can do the latter, a simple symbol is no challenge.

Comment: 2. The circles should not be ignored. They are needed to know which letters to type.

Comment: @Golez Sorry, didn't read that. Anyway, if anyone can identify a letter, he certainly can identify a circle too.

Comment: That's very true. Someone needs to add some intelligence to the algorithm, though, but once that's done, it is very easy to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I think captchas are used too frequently in places where they aren't the best tool. For instance, are you trying to prevent registration spam? Why use a captcha rather than email validation?

What are your intentions and have you considered alternatives to the (relatively ineffective) captcha technology?

As a side note, if you have to use them, I prefer KittyAuth myself :) http://thepcspy.com/kittenauth/#5

Answer (score 0):

Color blind people will have trouble separating red from green letters. People who have trouble reading and understanding descriptions, or have other disabilities may have trouble reading the captchas too. 
In some of these, the texts are so mangled that almost everyone has a hard time reading them.

I think captcha's, if used at all, should be quite easy to read. The one with the dots and triangles is doable, although it's a matter of time before someone writes an algorithm to hack them. It is very easy for computers to read this kind too.

The best way to deal with this, is increase moderation. Make your site so that it isn't rewarding to spam it at all. Don't make it the problem of your users.

Also, if you're gonna use captcha's, it may be better to build something yourself than to use common libraries. I've found that these are easier hacked, probably because it is more rewarding to write a captcha solver for something that is used by thhousands of sites.

Answer (score -1):

No matter which CAPTCHA you construct, spammers will find a way to work around it, given enough incentive. Large CAPTCHA services like reCAPTCHA, for instance, get bypassed by outsourcing solving them to cheap labor in India<sup>([source](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/inside-indias-captcha-solving-economy/1835))</sup>.

If you run a small site, your best bet is to make your own mini-CAPTCHA, which asks a simple question. If it isn't a standard question, isn't a standard CAPTCHA module and isn't a large site, it isn't worth it for the spammers to automate bypassing it.

I've been working on a community site for an organization at my university, and we've had trouble with spammers registering, despite us using every CAPTCHA module in the book. As soon as we made our own simple one-question CAPTCHA, all spam stopped. The key to preventing this sort of spam often lies in uniqueness.